# sqoop hive import job is running for long time and its Tracking URL is UNASSIGNED

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I am running hadoop on a single node cluster and Trying to sqoop import mysql data into hive tables.
The issue is while executing sqoop job, the process taking more time and data is not imported as shown below:

Sqoop command:

```
sqoop job --create Hcustomers --  import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retaildb --username root -P --table customers --check-column id --incremental append --last-value 0 --target-dir '/user/hive/retail/Hcustomers' -m 2;
```

After execution of sqoop job:

```
chaithu@localhost:~$ sqoop job --exec Hcustomers;
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/12/20 22:47:27 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.1
Enter password: 
17/12/20 22:47:32 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/12/20 22:47:32 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
Wed Dec 20 22:47:32 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
17/12/20 22:47:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `customers` AS t LIMIT 1
17/12/20 22:47:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `customers` AS t LIMIT 1
17/12/20 22:47:32 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-chaithu/compile/fa134412efb9ef64f2cb5a5ebfd29956/customers.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/12/20 22:47:34 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-chaithu/compile/fa134412efb9ef64f2cb5a5ebfd29956/customers.jar
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO tool.ImportTool: Maximal id query for free form incremental import: SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `customers`
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO tool.ImportTool: Incremental import based on column `id`
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO tool.ImportTool: Lower bound value: 0
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO tool.ImportTool: Upper bound value: 11
17/12/20 22:47:38 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
17/12/20 22:47:38 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
17/12/20 22:47:38 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of customers
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
17/12/20 22:47:38 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
17/12/20 22:47:39 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles: Permissions on staging directory /user/chaithu/.staging are incorrect: rwxrwx---. Fixing permissions to correct value rwx------
Wed Dec 20 22:47:45 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
17/12/20 22:47:45 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/12/20 22:47:45 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(`id`), MAX(`id`) FROM `customers` WHERE ( `id` > 0 AND `id` <= 11 )
17/12/20 22:47:45 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 5; Num splits: 2 from: 1 to: 11
17/12/20 22:47:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
17/12/20 22:47:46 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1513788823385_0002
17/12/20 22:47:46 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1513788823385_0002
17/12/20 22:47:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1513788823385_0002/
17/12/20 22:47:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1513788823385_0002
```

As shown above the execution gets stuck and no data is imported. Attaching the screen shot for job application.[Sqoop Job Status on Hadoop job tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQrNv.png)

I am just trying to import only 11 rows from mysql to hive, I think it should not take much time. What might be the issue. 
Kindly suggest me on the same.

Comment: Try avoiding `--incremental append` and see if it improves throughput. Also, how large in the table?

Comment: is your nodemanager running properly.. ?

Comment: @Petro: tried without incremental append using normal sqoop import  Yes node manager is running tried with below command:                           chaithu@localhost:~$ ps -ef | grep -i nodemanager
chaithu  22824 22521  0 11:14 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i nodemanager

Comment: may i know how did you solve this issue? i'm facing the same problem

Comment: I am facing same issue....Can somebody help on this?